# I can't install Uno.Check

Tags: uno-platform

When I attempt to install Uno.Check I get the baffling list of errors shown below.  This tool worked previously, but now something has changed.  If anyone can help me restore my environment and get this tool installed it would be greatly appreciated.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dotnet tool install -g Uno.Check

C:\Users\mark_000\AppData\Local\Temp\3eyg3mlz.yoa\restore.csproj(5,3): warning MSB4242: The SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildWorkloadSdkResolver" failed to run. Workload pack 'Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.Node' in manifest 'microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain' [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\6.0.100\microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain\WorkloadManifest.json] conflicts with manifest 'microsoft.net.workload.emscripten' [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\6.0.100\microsoft.net.workload.emscripten\WorkloadManifest.json]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props(14,3): warning MSB4242: The SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildWorkloadSdkResolver" failed to run. Workload pack 'Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.Node' in manifest 'microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain' [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\6.0.100\microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain\WorkloadManifest.json] conflicts with manifest 'microsoft.net.workload.emscripten' [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\6.0.100\microsoft.net.workload.emscripten\WorkloadManifest.json]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props(14,38): error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found. [C:\Users\mark_000\AppData\Local\Temp\3eyg3mlz.yoa\restore.csproj]
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'uno.check' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by uninstalling and then reinstalling Visual Studio 2022 17 Preview 3.1.  This restored my environment and now everything is back to normal again -- including Uno.Check version 0.1.1.

I'm not sure what scrambled my environment previously, but it may have been attempting to install and run Uno.Check version 0.2.0-dev.166.  Not only did this lead to the Uno-Check error messages reported above, but it also caused Visual Studio 2022 preview to fail when attempting to load projects.  However, this problem did not occur when using VS 2019 version 16.11.1. So whatever I did to scramble my environment was related to VS 2022 17 3.1

Comment: Same is happening to me. Reinstalling!